# Storing the standard distance of a centroid alongside the centroid coordinates

Tags: centroids, file-formats, format

I'd like to calculate and save a centroid (the central tendency) of a set of points as well as the standard distance (i.e. the root mean squared distance to the centroid). I can store the centroid as a point in any shapefile. As far as I know the only way to store the standard distance is as a shapefile attribute.

Is anyone aware of a more standardized way to store the standard distance alongside the centroid coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by "more standardized way"?

Comment: For example is there something in the Open Geospatial Consortium standards or something within GDAL that is designed to handle coordinate uncertainty.